# How to show local json file data in my browser extension in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, browser

I am trying to build an extension but my local json data is not being loaded in my extension

I try to fetch my local json data using fetch method but in my extension it shows a message in console like this TypeError: Failed to fetch

Please help me guys
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the code you are using

Comment: Hello @JoshuaLewis I just post my answer

Answer (score 0):

Hello guys I found out the solution you just have to put the json file in the public folder of react and do the following in your code if you are using fetch and I am using thunks in my redux so that i can manage my state in whole application

```
export function fetchProducts() {
    return async function fetchProductsThunks(dispatch, getState) {
        try {
            const res = await fetch("/results.json", {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/json'
                }
            })
            const data = await res.json()
            console.log(data)
            dispatch(setData(data))
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
}
```